# Read cyrillic from txt file

Tags: objective-c, cyrillic

There are similar threads, but didn't find answer.When read from txt (cyrillic) I got either \U00d0\U009d\U00d0 or ÐµÐ±Ðµ (win1251 or UTF8). Any solution to that? (first program).Thank you.

```
     NSString *bundlePathName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
     NSString *filePathName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/text.txt", bundlePathName];
     NSError *fileError;
     NSString *Content=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePathName  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&fileError];
```

gives \U00d0\U009d\U00d0, next one produces ÐµÐ±Ðµ

```
     const char *smth=[textContent cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSString *proba= [NSString stringWithCString:smth encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: What encoding is the text file encoded in?  What data are you expecting to get back?

Comment: tried 2 -first win1251 (old file), then made it in UTF8. Expect to get strings of text from array (1 case) with filtered array using predicate, second case- just tried to see if it's going to show cyrillic (text as NSString).

Comment: I guess there is smth with encoding from format to format, when used other file made from beginning with UTF8 - no problem.